# Git - Basic behavior working with branches

Tags: git, github, version-control

Working with Git 2.13.5, a very simple question to check if it's me misunderstanding something or a wrong behavior working with branches.

Follow this steps:

1. Initial situation: I have a certain repository with only one branch ("master").
2. `git checkout -b some-changes`
3. Open `some_file.js` in favorite editor and add some changes. Close the file.
4. `git status` (I see the modified file waiting to be staged (in red))
5. Imagine I have an important bug now in Production. I do `git checkout master`
6. When I open again `some_file.js`, I still see the changes in the file, although I have changed to master.
7. When I do `git status`, I still see the modified file waiting to be staged (in red)).

Aren't steps 6 and 7 wrong? Since I changed to master branch, shouldn't I see the original unmodified `some_file.js` and all `up-to-date` in the `git status` command?

Comment: If you didn't `add` the file, then it's just an untracked file, so it shouldn't be reverted (I think, I'm no git guru). If you try adding `some_file.js` to the branch, then checkout, you should find it's gone.

Comment: Does `some_file.js` already exist in the repo or is it a newly created file at step 3?

Comment: No, this is expected behavior. Changes not committed belong to the working tree, not a particular branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this is often very surprising to new Git users, it's actually a fundamentally sensible and normal thing in Git.  It all has to do with Git's model of how commits are to be done, and how you are to do work in your work-tree.  Also, though only tangentially related here, branches don't mean as much in Git as they do in most version control systems.

#### Committed files

Any Version Control System (VCS) must have some way of storing the versioned files.  In Git, rather than storing files directly, Git stores *commits*.  A commit represents a complete snapshot of *all* of your files.  Well, we should say *almost all*, or even *some specific subset*, here.  And, each commit usually has exactly one *parent* commit: that's the commit that *was* the current commit, back when whoever made the new commit, made the new commit.

#### The current commit: `HEAD` or `@`

In other words, at all times, you always have some *current commit*.  This current commit, which you can name with `@` or with the word `HEAD`, is a permanent (mostly), unchangeable (completely) snapshot of a bunch of files.  The `HEAD` name actually contains the *name of the current branch*, and the branch-name then resolves to the commit hash ID.

#### Your work-tree

It's those files that you got into your *work-tree* when you ran `git clone` to clone the repository.  But the work-tree is just *where you do your work*.  You need a place to do this, because the current commit, `HEAD`, *can't* be changed.  (Besides that, the files stored in the current commit are stored in a special, Git-only format.  Other programs on your computer, including your editor and your `.js` file handlers, probably can't deal with it.)

#### The index, and untracked files

Now, a file in your work-tree, like `some_file.js`, is merely that: a file in your work-tree.  There may be a corresponding file in the current (`HEAD`) commit, or there may not.  That's important; but even more important is whether there is another copy of this file in your *index*.  The index is perhaps best described as: *What Git will put into your next commit.*

Git's index is kind of mysterious, because you can't actually look at it directly.  The closest you can get is to run `git ls-files --stage` (which can produce quite a lot of output and is not normally useful anyway).  This index, also called the *staging area* and sometimes the *cache*, starts out holding another copy of every file that's in the `HEAD` commit.  This copy, like the one in `HEAD`, is in a special Git-only format, compressed down to just a tiny little index number, that ultimately just says "same as the `HEAD` version", so it doesn't really take any extra space.  Still, it's *there*.

If a file is in the index, Git calls this file *tracked*.  If the file is *not* in the index, Git calls it *untracked*.  This is very important, but since your file is tracked, we won't worry about this yet.

If you want the updated contents from your work-tree to go into a new commit, you must copy the work-tree file to the index:

```
git add some-file.js
```

Now the new version is in the index, ready to be committed.

#### Git's `checkout` is especially tricky

In Git, branch names like `some-changes` really just name *one specific commit*.  Each commit names its own parent, too, so at this point, you have:

```
... <-- o <--o <--o   <-- master, some-changes (HEAD)
```

Both `some-changes` and `master` point to the *same commit* (same big ugly hash ID).  So `git checkout master` puts the name `master` into `HEAD`, but sees that it does not have to touch the index or work-tree, because it's not actually changing *commits*.  After the checkout you have:

```
... <-- o <--o <--o   <-- master (HEAD), some-changes
```

The index and work-tree are unchanged, so `git status`—which compares `HEAD` vs index, and the index vs work-tree—is also unchanged, except for which branch name it prints when it says `on branch ...`.

Comment: Great in-depth explanation! Wish I could upvote this more than once.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

On step 4, you have local changes to the file `some_file.js`. Git will respect these changes and requires you to explicitly decide what to do with them when you check out a branch. By default, these changes will still be in your local working copy. If the changes conflict with changes in the branch, git will complain and not allow you to check out the branch.

You have several choices to manage this:

1. Throw away your changes with `git rest --hard HEAD`.
2. Keep your changes in your local copy and work on the new branch as you want.
3. Commit your changes before step 5 in the usual manner.
4. Temporarily save your changes with `git stash` and reload them at a later time with `git stash apply` or `git stash pop`.